# C++ and header file zipped web files byte array for progmem

Tags: c++

I’m currently trying to teach myself little by little how to code a WiFi interface for a nodeMCU. I’m using code I found on github and other various places as a template to learn how each part works.

I’m stuck now and would really appreciate help getting over this mental road block. I have spent a lot of time developing html css and JavaScript code to use in my Arduino sketch however understanding how this template uploaded the web file to SPIFFS is giving me all kinds of problems.

```
#ifndef webfiles_h

#define webfiles_h

#define USE_PROGMEM_WEB_FILES 

#ifdef USE_PROGMEM_WEB_FILES
const char indexhtml[] PROGMEM = {0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x08, 0xb6, 0x41, 0xf9, 0x5b, 0x02, 0xff, 0x69, 0x6e,...
#endif

void copyWebFiles(bool force){

#ifdef USE_PROGMEM_WEB_FILES

if(settings.getWebSpiffs()){
if(!SPIFFS.exists(String(F("/web/index.html.gz"))) || force) progmemToSpiffs(indexhtml, sizeof(indexhtml), String(F("/web/index.html.gz")));

}
#endif
}
#endif
```

The above code is essentially what the template does.

What I want to do is create my “webfiles.h” but the specific part I don’t understand is the code that looks like this

```
const char indexhtml[] PROGMEM = {0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x08, 0xb6, 0x41, 0xf9, 0x5b, 0x02, 0xff, 0x69, 0x6e,...
```

**Question:**

**How do I convert a zipped html file to a byte array to use in a webfiles.h file with progmem**

I’ve tried:

Converting to base64 but it’s obviously not the same.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the github you linked is what will turn my zipped html files to a byte array for progmem???

Comment: The sequence of events will help you identify the start and end of a gzipped file, you handle the bytes in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are hexadecimal numbers representing the bytes of the file.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/hexadecimal_arithmetic.htm
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/binary/bin_3.html

The 0x prefix indicates that the number is to be parsed as hexadecimal. 0xFF means 255, 0x100 means 256, etc. We often use this when printing bytes because the maximum value of a byte is 255 (0xFF), so you can always print a byte using max two characters using hexadecimal numbers. With our normal base10 numbers we'd have to write '255' which uses three digits. This makes formatting simpler. Imagine you have to print 6 bytes after each other

> Decimal: 0 255 128 100 200 30
>
> Hexadecimal: 00 FF 80 64 C8 1E

See how hexadecimal is better formatted? You can represent any byte using two characters. They can sometimes be harder to read, you're just gonna have to get used to it.

To generate a byte array of a file yourself you can use the tool HxD and export to a C header file.
https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/

It's also super simple to create a tool to do this yourself, I did it a while ago in probably less than 50 lines of code.